# Creating labels,dropdown box using Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Iknow the basics of backbone.js creating model , coll, view. but how to create attributes for the below script  in a model  and how to view it in a template?

```
<table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                       <label>T:</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label>F</label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                       <label>Fi:</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="fi" readonly="true"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>             
                <tr>
                    <td>
                       <label>Ba:</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select id="ba">
                           <option value="4">1200</option>
                           <option value="5">2400</option>
                           <option value="6">4800</option>
                           <option value="7">9600</option>
                           <option value="8">19200</option>                           
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label>St:</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="radio" name="st" value="0" checked="checked" > one
                        <input type="radio" name="st" value="1"> two
                    </td>
                </tr></table>
```

can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

You can store "ba" keyvalues in one field in your model as {key:value} data like that:

```
var mdl = new Backbone.Model({ba:{1:1200, 2:2400}});

var SelectView = Backbone.View.extend({
                             template: _.template($("#mytemplate").text()),
                             render: function() {
                                 this.$el = $(this.el);
                                 this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.attributes));
                                 return this;
                             }
                            });
var view = new SelectView({model: mdl})
```

and then, template

```
<script type="template/html" id="mytemplate">
  <select id="ba">
    <% for (key in ba) { %>
    <option value="<%=key%>"><%=ba[key]%></option>
    <% } %>
  </select>
</script>
```

I skip other things in your template, and show one way, how you can create "select" with options.

You can read about Backbone.View.render [here](http://backbonejs.org/#View-render)

And about template engine (from underscore) [here](http://underscorejs.org/#template)

Comment: in case of radio buttons wat to do?

Comment: just edit template, no matter, radio buttons, checkboxes or selects. Just change #mytemplate to anything you need. Maybe you need to view worked example... like that http://backbonejs.org/examples/todos/index.html

Comment: now for st i have 2 radio buttons....wat can be done for this to add this as model attributes.i have to add dropdown,check,radiobox,label as model attributes then view it in a template.

Comment: You can add this attributes to model, and then use it in your template like in my example

Comment: am not able to add labels n radio buttons as u said me...also i wan the template to look like Ba://dropdownbox//..how to do dis...can u explain me wit a example as u did for dropdown..

Comment: can I pass like var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
var mdl = new Backbone.Model({ba:array}); ??

Comment: of course. But then if you need to take array  values you need use get method. for example mdl.get("ba")[0] (if you need first value of the array)